# why mouse event 's position have wrong in kineticjs?

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

i have a kineticjs, i use  tag to get kineticjs canvas's position is center

```
#mycanvas{text-align:center;}
```

And when run it, event area far from object 200px , at left side of object.
I can't understand the reason?
Thank for all answer!

Comment: Showing us the javascript might help, but I'm gonna venture a guess that you're not using `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`

Comment: I have just come across the same issue. If the canvas (or it's container) is text-align:center, mouseover events are not detected correctly (in chrome and FF - things still seem to work in IE).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, the following work-around worked for me;

```
            $("#container canvas:last").css("position", "relative");
```

Not nice, but hopefully this helps someone.